# WCF service blocked by Windows Firewall

Tags: wcf, http, firewall

I've got a WCF service using a HttpBinding. The service is running in a self hosting process (A Windows Service) and this process is inside the Windows Firewall exceptions list.

If the Firewall is active and I'm trying to access the service using a C# client or Internet Explorer, the service does not respond. But if the Firewall is disabled the connection works like a charm.

Does anyone have expirence with WCF and the Windows Firewall? The problem came up on Windows 7 64bit. I didn't try another OS yet.

What am I supposed to do to get this working with an active Firewall?

Regards Michael

EDIT:
I found a clue, that the http.sys has to be added to the firewall exceptions list, as wcf self hosting uses http.sys. Any advices, how to solve this?

EDIT: 
I tried opening all listening port manually, which works too, but is not an option, because I don't know them in advance.

Comment: try to open the port the service uses? i.e port 80, 8080 or whatever you have configured. Since it uses regular http i can't see the problem :(

Comment: I just tried that and it works. But in order to provide a simple user experiance, this is not an option in productive environment. (It appears that the port is changed...)

Comment: Sounds weird that the port would change? Are you using IIS to publish the service? I guess you would have to do a routine that checks which port the service uses now and open that port programatically in the firewall, if that's even possible. If the port is closed in the firewall you probably won't be able to access the service.

Comment: The firewall is configured by the setup routine of the application. At this point I don't know which port the service will use, maybe the user will change the default setting. So I need to open the firewall based on processes, not ports. The service is self hostet (no IIS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the MSDN article *[Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx)*.

Comment: Finally... I'm not sure if this is the intension of your answer, but the article states that: "Self-hosted HTTP addressing for WCF is not integrated into the Windows personal firewall. An exception must be added to the firewall configuration to allow inbound connections using a particular URL." I think the 'exception' is ment to be a port exception (not process). At least this is my experience.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, adding self hosted WCF service process to firewall does not work, because it is not that process taking inbound calls, it only works if

1. add service port to global port exception
2. add WCF inbound daemon process to process exception, I'm not sure about http, but for net.tcp bindings, you need $FrameworkDir/SMSvcHost.exe instead of your process.